# Getting `Unsupported get request` error only on certain ID

Tags: facebook

I'll start with example, so it will be easier to understand. So I have this script:

```
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('536443039714362', '007d98b0f51f3ffecb206987fc3bc624');
        $session = new FacebookSession('access-token');
        $session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
        $event = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/loftasvilnius'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className())->asArray();
```

As you see It gets info of page with prefix 'loftasvilnius'. And everything works fine here.

Hovewer if I change name of page to 'Opiumclub'. API throws this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api' in D:\xampp\htdocs\fb\src\Facebook\FacebookRequestException.php:104 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\fb\src\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php(268): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...',
```

Could someone explain that's wrong here ?

I tried to do this through graph explorer in facebook dev page. And here it worked ok.